# Leaflet js add polygon with offset around another polygon

Tags: polygon, leaflet

I am pretty new in working with Leaflet js and I have a polygon

```
var coords = layer.getLatLngs();
L.polygon(coords, { fillColor: 'red', fillOpacity: 0.5, weight: 20, color: 'red', opacity: 0.5, fill: true}).addTo(map);
```

and I need to add another polygon around it with an offset.
I've tried using `leaflet.polylineoffset`, first with `polyline`

```
coords.push(coords[0]);
L.polyline(coords, { color: 'purple', weight: 2, opacity: 0.7, fill: false, offset: 10}).addTo(map);
```

but it didn't close properly

[image]

Then, by using `polygon`,

```
L.polygon(coords, { color: 'purple', weight: 2, opacity: 0.7, fill: false, offset: 10, polygon: true }).addTo(map);
```

it draws one of the line on top of the other polygon

[image]

Is there a way to add a polygon around an existing one with an offset?

Comment: What should be the offset unit: meters or pixels?

Comment: @TomazicM both are good

Comment: But completely different in behavior. Pixel offset stays the same regardless of zoom, offset in meters visually changes with zoom.

Comment: @TomazicM For the red polygon I'm changing the stroke weight when the zoom changes (to keep the size in meters) and I think meters would be best in this case

Comment: This is a "turfjs buffer" problem.

Comment: @IvanSanchez How can I use Turf JS buffer for my polygon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to solve this is to actually use `Leaflet.PolylineOffset` plugin, with slight modification of plugin code (only one line):

```
.
.
.
joinLineSegments: function(segments, offset) {
    var joinedPoints = [];
    var first = segments[0];
    var last = segments[segments.length - 1];

    if (first && last) {
        joinedPoints.push(first.offset[0]);
        forEachPair(segments, L.bind(function(s1, s2) {
            joinedPoints = joinedPoints.concat(this.joinSegments(s1, s2, offset));
        }, this));
        joinedPoints = joinedPoints.concat(this.joinSegments(last, first, offset));  // added line
//      joinedPoints.push(last.offset[1]);   // removed line
    }

    return joinedPoints;
},
.
.
.
```

Example after this modification:

[image]